# MySQL SUM distinct rows based on foreign key without subquery

Tags: mysql, sum

I have the following MySQL tables, where B_ID is a foreign key pointing to the ID column of Table_B:

```
----------    -----------
|Table_A |    |Table_B  |
----------    -----------
|B_ID int|    |ID int   |
----------    |VALUE int|
              -----------
```

I want to compute the sum of the VALUE column in Table_B considering only IDs that appear as foreign keys in Table_A. Also, I want to add each row in Table_B at most once.

So, if the tables were filled with the following data:

```
------    ------------
|B_ID|    |ID | VALUE|
------    ------------
|1   |    |1  | 50   |
|2   |    |2  | 100  |
|2   |    |3  | 200  |
------    ------------
```

the sum would be 150 (computed as 50+100).

The query I am using now is:

```
SELECT SUM(b.VALUE)
FROM Table_B b
WHERE b.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT B_ID FROM Table_A)
```

However, I would like to avoid having a subquery if at all possible. Any ideas on how to do this without subqueries?

Note: This query is itself a subquery in a larger query, so it can only select one column.

Answer (score 1):

This does not eliminate subqueries, but would be more efficient if you have few records in `a` and lots in `b`:

```
SELECT  SUM(value)
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT b_id
        FROM    a
        ) a
JOIN    b
ON      b.id = a.b_id
```

Create an index on `a.b_id` for this to work fast.

If there are few records in `b` and lots of them in `a`, your original query will be faster. The suggestion of the index still applies.

Comment: Thanks. This is a nice approach, although I can't use it my real-life scenario because the query will be nested in a larger query and some additional constraints on Table_A will not work due to some fields being inaccessible (basically, the problem stated here http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16029)